# Is EM wave always time-harmonic in free space?

Tags: electromagnetic

Is EM wave always time-harmonic in free space ?

Can non-time-harmonic EM wave not exist?

Comment: Ask this in [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: In the sense that any wave can be decomposed into sinusoidal components (Fourier transform; which may further require a linear medium so that the superposition of sine waves is meaningful), sure. If you mean without transforms, sure, a static spark emits a single pulse with a sharp wavefront for example.

Comment: @Tim Williams !!! awesome!! thank you very much!!!

Comment: The harmonic time recursion depends the  lack of variation in spectrum of the source, the path length and reflections (which might be assumed constant but could be rain or wet leaves or ice etc)

Comment: @BriL, All propagating waves can be decomposed into their plane-wave spectra when in a homogeneous and time-invarient medium. At each temporal frequency there will be a unique set of vector plane waves that combine into the observed field. But the math becomes less intuitive for us non-geniuses. For insight, we replace vector field with scalar addition, use an approximating propagator (Huygens integral) and accept small cone angles, use Fourier (works here but overly simple when surfaces are added), and use asymptotic theory that ignores diffraction (also doesn't matter in your case.)

Comment: @periblepsis, Hoagie   Thank you for yours comment.  This is too hard to understand.   I will think more deeply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is EM wave always time-harmonic in free space ?

No, electro magnetic fields can be static or not. Some EM waves are harmonic, like light and radio waves.

> Can non-time-harmonic EM wave not exist?

Yes you can have waves that are not synchronized between their magnetic and electric field components, these waves attenuate. You can have waves with only a magnetic component or only an electric component

Comment: I really appreciate for your guidance !!!      Where can I possibly find example or explanation [that have waves with only a magnetic component or only an eletric component] ?    book title or article title or internet site....    if possible.. [waves that are not synchronized between their magnetic and electric field components]... also...

Comment: Is it right  that  [waves that are not synchronized between their magnetic and electric field components] is EM wave in a lossy medium ??

Comment: They can be synchronized or not, lossy means the wave gets attenuated by the medium, and the amplitude decreases with propagation if you want to learn more get an EM textbook or research antennas, light, near field, far field, transmission and reflection